# Что будет если удалить ветку main

Tags: git, github

Раньше у меня был код в репозитории github в ветке main, потом выяснилось что мне нужны разные версии приложения под разные операционные системы. Я сделал отдельную ветку с именем winodws куда положил версию под виндовс, и ветку с именем linuix64, куда положил версию для linux. Ветка main осталась, но она мне больше не нужна. Но, так как windows и linux64 были созданы на основе main, у меня возник вопрос, что произойдет, если я удалю main? потеряю ли я код в остальных ветках? И вообще могу ли я удалить ветку main?

Comment: .можно удалить.

Comment: main (ок, master) такая же ветка, как и все другие. Не нужно - удаляйте.

Comment: ветка указывает на последний свой коммит. Если к этому коммиту можно добраться с других веток то можно спокойно эту ветку удалить. Иначе все коммиты, которые доступны **только** ветке master будут *почти* недоступны.